# CardDAV server with Java API (or working CardDAV Java Client API)

Tags: java, api, webdav, ical4j, carddav

Is there any CardDAV Server which can be accessed via Java API?

Another possibility would be to have a working(!) CardDAV Client Java API. The only library I found was `ical4j` but couldn't get it to read my contacts from owncloud.

I also tried `radicale` server. ical4j was able to connect and write contacts, but I'm not sure if everything worked, 'cause I was not able to connect to radicale using iOS and OSX...

Answer (score 0):

Doing client side Carddav requires you to do 2 different things:
- correctly format vCard data
- interact with the server via webdav

Cardme will correctly format the vCard data (i use it heaps!) - https://github.com/george-haddad/cardme

For interacting with the server (ie browsing and uploading) you need a webdav library. Sardine is good.

Brad

Comment: And that's all? Doesn't CardDAV provide lot's of additional features compared to WebDAV?

Comment: Not really, CardDav requires everything Webdav level 2 has, plus it requires ACL, and it requires properties to access the vCard data. And in practise well-known support is required for iOS. And it requires a few reports and things for efficient syncronisation, but theres not much else.